# How can I convert all forms of a specific word in a String to lowercase?

Tags: java, uppercase, lowercase

I'm in my first semester in coding and completely stuck on this one.

I want to get all forms of a word (ex: HeLLo, hEllO, heLlo, ...) to change to lowercase and don't know how to get there without writing a condition for every single variation in my file. I have many words I have to convert to either lowercase or uppercase so I realized that there must be a better way of doing but can't figure out which.

Is there a way to get all of these variations at once and convert them to lowercase?

Input = " HeLlo this is my program called HELLO "

Output = " hello this is my program called hello "

I've only tried:

word.replace("HELLO", "hello");

word.replace("Hello", "hello");
and so on..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a regex solution:

```
word = word.replaceAll("(?i)hello", "hello");
```

This is a "case-insensitive" replacement; i.e., all instances of "hello" regardless of case (Hello, HeLlO, HELLO, etc.) will be replaced with "hello".

I found [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) article to be particularly helpful when learning regex. [Here](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/zAr)'s a live working example.

Answer (score 2):

```
word.toLowerCase()
```

or for the opposite

```
word.toUpperCase()
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Note - If you want to change specific words as part of a string, you will have to iterate through every word in the inputted string

Comment: wouldn't that take the whole string and convert it to lowercase/uppercase? I only need that specific word in all forms of capitalization to convert without altering the other words in the string

Comment: I will alter my answer to show you how you can do that, do you have an example of some words?

Comment: I'm learning coding in french so trying to find examples is kinda hard lol.. The input in my original post, I'd want the HeLlo and HELLO to be in lowercase, but in my file, there would be TONS of variations of that word (hEllo, heLlo, ...) so I would want all of them to go lowercase without having to do them one by one if possible

Comment: I have added a new answer hopefully explaining to you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **java.util.regex.Pattern** with the **CASE_INSENSITIVE** Option:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("hallo"), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String test = "Hallo FoO HallO BaR HaLLo BAz";  
String replaced = pattern.matcher(test).replaceAll("hallo");
// Output: hallo FoO hallo BaR hallo BAz
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing that your input text is the value 'text' (you can make the variable names whatever you want), it should output the correct string.
You can add words you want to change to lowercase and uppercase (make sure when you add them they are in lower case)

```
String text = "Hello I am No GoodBYE";
        String[] lowercase = {"hello", "goodbye"};
        String[] uppercase = {"no", "yes"};
        String[] split_string = text.split(" ");
        for (int i=0;i < split_string.length;i++){
            for (String low:lowercase){
                if (split_string[i].toLowerCase().equals(low)){
                    split_string[i] = split_string[i].toLowerCase();
                }

        }
            for (String upper:uppercase){
                if (split_string[i].toLowerCase().equals(upper)){
                    split_string[i] = split_string[i].toUpperCase();
                }
            }
    }
        String final_result = "";
        for(String word:split_string){
            final_result = final_result + " " + word;
        }
        System.out.println(final_result);
```

Comment: I've tried it and it worked! Although I'm afraid I might not be able to use it as we haven't learn some parts of the code you've written so my teacher might not accept it, I went with the regex way another user recommended, thanks alot for your help :) !

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

- Change the whole string to lower: `HeLlo There heLLO WorlD` -> `hello there hello world`
- Look for the index of the target word: indexes of `"hello"` -> `[0, 12]`
- Change the indexes in the original: `hello There hello WorlD`

pseudo

```java
String toLower(String input, String replacement) {
     indices = input.toLower().allIndecesOf(replacement)
     result = input.clone()
     for i in indices {
        result = result.replace( i, replacement )
     }
     return result
}
```